# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, highcharts

I'm currently working on creating some highcharts using data from Firebase.

I found an example here:

http://blog.dotnetnerd.dk/post/2014/01/27/Realtime-data-displays-with-Firebase.aspx

However, when I try and load it into my application I receive the following error:

> firebase.js:43 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of
>   undefined
>
> ```
> at app.html:343
> at firebase.js:93
> at ic (firebase.js:43)
> at Wd (firebase.js:93)
> at Ud.Jb (firebase.js:93)
> at be.Xd.Jb (firebase.js:94)
> at firebase.js:109
> at firebase.js:59
> at cc (firebase.js:55)
> at R (firebase.js:59)
> ```

The JS and HTML for the highchart looks like this:

```js
var fb = new Firebase("https://<ProjectName>.firebaseio.com/products"); 
    fb.on("value", function(data) { 
        var model = data.val(); 
          $('#container').highcharts({ 
            chart: { type: 'column' }, 
            title: { text: 'Sales' }, 
            xAxis: { 
                categories: model.Categories 
            }, 
            yAxis: { title: { text: 'Quantity' } }, 
            series: model.Series.map(function(element) { 
                return { 
                    name: element.Name, 
                    data: element.Data 
                } 
            })                        
        });                
    });
```

```html
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

Here is the JSON:

[image: JSON]

If anyone knows why this error is occurring and how to solve it, it will be much appreciated.

Thank you,

G

Comment: Most likely it is because you don't have `Series` property in your model. You may need to check the format of your products data.

Comment: All is formatted correctly

Comment: How does your model.Series look like?

Comment: @morganfree I have added it to the question for you to see

Comment: As was commented before - Series is undefined,  so you need to check if this object is correct and have access to map function. Also, data structure for Highcharts does not look correct - I recommend to read this part of docs https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series

Answer (score -1):

You must use your own project name in the first line :

```
https://<ProjectName>.firebaseio.com/products
```

Change `<ProjectName>` with your firebase url. You can see which is in your firebase account.

Comment: Hi Merunas, In my actual code I have changed this - But for security reasons I simply changed it back to <ProjectName> for the example